# Background color under image doesn't work in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I want to make a background image on my webpage, and a background color under it so the places where the picture end you can see the color.

I tried it 3 ways: 
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title> title</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 header">
            dssadsasddsads
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and I tried 3 css combinations I found none of which work:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('img/bg6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-color: #EE2020;}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #EE2020 url('img/bg6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: url('img/bg6.jpg'), #EE2020;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I found the problem. The bootstrap CSS file had background-color set to white and I had to override it adding !important to the background-color property in my layout file.

Comment: Your last `<body>` tag works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/on0wj9m8/1/

Comment: Why doesn't it work when I try it on my computer on my browser? I tried chrome and firefox and both show a white background.

Comment: You'd have to use an image type that supports **transparency** like PNG. JPG files do **not**.

Comment: The issue was overriding the bootstrap css, but thanks for the effort guys :)

Comment: Instead of appending the solution to your question, there’s nothing wrong with submitting an answer to your own question and accepting it as the correct answer. This way the question will be marked as solved, and people experiencing the same issue will easily find what worked for you :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: url('img/bg6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

html {
    background: #EE2020 !important;
}
```

This will work fine!

Answer (score 0):

[Avoid using `!important` where you can](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/#when-should-important-be-used).

Your options here are to include your stylesheet  **after** bootstrap or learn about [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). A more specific rule that could work is:

```
html > body { background-color: #EE2020;}
```

Adding classes or id also can give you a more specific rule, but you should be able to avoid that in this case.

It is important to remember if you want to override a library like bootstrap, to include your styles **after** the library, this is the way CSS has been designed. It's part of the "Cascade" (the C in CSS). Knowing how to use specificity to resolve any other conflicts is also important.